# Multicolumn Footnote with kableExtra on Quarto document

Tags: r, quarto, kable, kableextra

I have a table generated with kableExtra with a footnote that spans over several columns. If I run it separately in R it displays properly. However, when run inside a Quarto document, it constraints the text of the footnote to the width of the 1st column.

Here is a reproducible example

```
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:4]

# HTML table
kbl(dt, caption = "Demo Table") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped",
                full_width = F) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2[note]" = 2)) %>%
  footnote(c("Let's make a very long table footnote"))
```

[image]
Has any one experienced this before, and if so knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be bug, I would open an issue. In the meantime, you might try the parse-latex filter and first build the table as a latex table and then let the filter convert it to HTML, i.e.

````
---
format: html
filters: [parse-latex]
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:4]

# HTML table
kbl(dt,format = "latex", caption = "Demo Table") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped",
                full_width = F) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2[note]" = 2)) %>%
   footnote(general = "Here is a general comments of the table that might be very long. "
           )
```
````

Comment: Excellent. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When knitting Quarto to PDF (via LaTeX) adding `threeparttable = TRUE` argument to `footnote()` works:

```
# In LaTeX format

base::library(package = kableExtra)
    dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:4]

# PDF table
kableExtra::kbl(
  x        = dt, 
  caption  = "Demo Table",
  booktabs = TRUE
) %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(
    bootstrap_options = "striped",
    full_width        = FALSE
  ) %>%
  kableExtra::add_header_above(
    c(
      " ", 
      "Group 1" = 2, 
      "Group 2[note]" = 2
    )
  ) %>%
  kableExtra::footnote(
    general           = "Let's make a very long table footnote",
    threeparttable    = TRUE, # PAY ATTENTION HERE
    footnote_as_chunk = TRUE
  )
```

This is using the threeparttable LaTeX package to produce the effect that we want. This option is explicitly mentioned [here](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf).

With HTML, I'm afraid this problem is much more difficult because you wont have access to LaTeX packages so `threeparttable = TRUE` won't work. Plyaing around with your code - I noticed that removing your header row actually allowed the text to extend more. So removing this code produced that effect:

```
  kableExtra::add_header_above(
    c(
      " ", 
      "Group 1" = 2, 
      "Group 2[note]" = 2
    )
  ) %>%
```

Based on that, the footnote wrapping is somehow due to the formatting of the header column of the groups. I played with arguments of the many functions and was unable to find a definitive way to prevent the text wrapping. It seems like some folks have had some issues with the new(er) Quarto format and this package, maybe worth reading some of the open issues [here](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues?q=quarto).

In light of all of this, I'd recommend either switching to PDF format, forgoing the header row, or looking into other packages that may be able to accomplish this (`gt` maybe?).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explore this. I need to work with HTML, so no PDF for the time being. I will read through the open issues, and maybe even open one of my own.

Comment: No problem! I'd definitely recommend coming back here to edit if you find a solution - I may need it myself in the future ;)

Comment: Definitively! If Quarto is going to become the law of the land as Posit wants, this glitches should get ironed out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the workaround I used is to add a figure caption:

````
```{r adjacent-treatment-estimates, fig.cap="The title of the table"}
table%>%
footnote(footnote_as_chunk = TRUE,
       threeparttable = TRUE,
       general = "Estimates with baseline TWFE model. Municipality and year FE. Standard Errors clustered at Municipality level.")
```
````